# Is there any solution for verifyPurchase in In-app-Purchase for ios flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-functions, in-app-purchase

I am implementing In-app purchases in my flutter app, there is the last step to verify the purchase by making a cloud function named to verify the purchase. I made a function and deployed it successfully to firebase but when I am testing this function in postman I got an error of bad request also when I use this function in the flutter app I got false each time.
Please help me do this accurately or recommend any tutorial/article.

I tried to implement cloud function in two ways. first one is here

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as Functions from "firebase-functions";
import {CLOUD_REGION,PURCHASE_TOKEN } from "./constants";
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const functions = Functions.region(CLOUD_REGION);
admin.initializeApp();

export const verifyPurchase = functions.https.onCall(
    async (
        context,
    ): Promise<any> => {
      const response = await fetch("https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "receipt-data": PURCHASE_TOKEN,
        "password": PURCHASE_PASSWORD
        "exclude-old-transactions": true,
      }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: '/',
      },
    });
 
    if(response.ok){
      return response.body;
    }else {
      return response.error;
    }
 
    });

while test on postman getting this response
 {
    "result": {
        "size": 0,
        "timeout": 0
    }
}
```